# Publishing html file in AzureDevOps

Tags: html, azure, azure-devops

I have a process that generates a set of HTML files and subfolder containing CSS/Javascript files.

I thought I could use the publish-pipeline-artifact to publish this HTML report and have it displayed but it doesn't work.

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/publish-pipeline-artifact?view=azure-devops

Is there another way ?

Comment: Please provide more info on what you are attempting to publish to (a VM, and App Service Plan, Storage Account) and what is not working.

Comment: Hello, thanks for your help, I upvoted it but my report is composed of HTML+JS+CSS files, I don't see how it will work.

Answer (score 4):

Azure DevOps can understand a report if it is in the format of a format called **TRX**.

Once the report is generated, you can upload using the [Azure DevOps workflow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/pipelines/tasks/test/publish-test-results?view=vsts) function

For html report, one way would be deploy the html files to a web page which allow iframe embedding and then use "Embedded Webpage" widget in Azure DevOps to show the content.

Comment: My report is composed of HTML, jS and css it's not in TRX or standard formats.

Answer (score 2):

I think you meant something like what in [this feature request](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/idea/491426/support-for-generic-html-publishing-inside-build-a.html) is asked.